# How to control volume of left and right channel of a headset separately using Naudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I m working on a project in which I need to send two audio files to separate (left and right) channel and control each channel volume separately. I have achieved  the 1 case however I didn't get anything for the 2nd one. My code for playing two audio files to separate channel is:

```
var input1 = new Mp3FileReader(@"C:\Users\Public\Music\Kala.mp3");

var input2 = new Mp3FileReader(@"C:\Users\Public\Music.mp3"); 

MultiplexingWaveProvider waveProvider = new MultiplexingWaveProvider(new IWaveProvider[] { input1, input2 }, 2);

waveProvider.ConnectInputToOutput(1, 0);

waveProvider.ConnectInputToOutput(3, 1);
WaveOut wave = new WaveOut(); 
wave.Init(waveProvider); 
wave.Play();
```

Help on the second will be appreciated.
Thanks and regards

Comment: Mark made his life difficult by writing this class, too many programmers assume that it does something else than it was meant to do.  You need a fancy soundcard that supports multiple outputs, ASIO is their standard interface.  Never WaveOut.  So this can't work, you need to do the mixing yourself with your own wave provider.

Comment: It's good that everybody is using Mark excellent work... If audio can be channelized then some functionalities should be there to control their volume also.. I m not aware that's why wrote a question... Somebody please help..

Answer (score 0):

If you use `AudioFileReader` instead of `Mp3FileReader` that will give you a convenient Volume property on each input. There are several other ways of achieving the same thing, but that's probably the simplest.